# Fine Uploader with Amazon S3, s3Key vs UUID clarification

Tags: fine-uploader

The response to the initial file list request initially sent by Fine Uploader requires according to the documentation, at least the follow items: name, uuid, s3Key, blobName.
As the documentation says, s3Key is for Amazon S3 usage, blobName is for MS Azure.  That is clear.  However if providing the s3Key for use with Amazon S3 is the implementation, can the uuid be excluded?  Just want to clarify how the uuid is used when dealing with Amazon S3 objects, and if the uuid is not provided correctly what are the guidelines for doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`name` and `uuid` are always required in your server's response to the initial file list GET request.  The UUID is simply sent as a parameter back to your server when a delete request is made.  The UUID is also required by some internal components of Fine Uploader for tracking purposes.  IF you want to use the initial file list feature, you should be storing the UUID Fine Uploader assigns each file along with the file record in your DB.  If you aren't doing this, you can probably just generate a new UUID for each canned/initial file and return it in your response to the initial file GET.  If you choose to do this, and you are utilizing the delete file feature, you may need to be sure and persist this association server-side.